On-prem SSIS package deployed to SQL Server hangs on timeout connecting to Azure hosted vm SQL Server rather than terminating
On-prem SSIS package deployed to on-prem SQL Server db(Standard running in datacenter 2016) hangs on timeout connecting to Azure hosted VM SQL Server rather than terminating.
Recently, we've moved from remote hosting in a "local" datacenter to Azure.  Before the change, the deployed package would experience errors and terminate. Then a SQL Agent would restart the package.  It was effective to keep it running for weeks at a time without human intervention.
Since the change to Azure, the deployed app hangs at least every 36 hours, mainly on a timeout connecting to SQL database running on Azure VM. So it requires a lot of baby-sitting. I want it to terminate so my agent job can come along in short order and restart it.
Any ideas what might need to be different?  Yes, I queried an AI tool... but you people might have something better than the 30 general ideas AI spits at me.
Note: this is using MSOLEDBSQL driver to connect to remote AZ hosted db. I just changed this to MSOLEDBSQL19(version from April, '24) Also, changed timeout to 120 seconds and expanded to 10 retry attempts... but that doesn't address the "Hang" vs "terminate" issue.
